# How do I replace hook_field_widget_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter() with hook_field_widget_complete_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter()?

Tags: hooks, 10

I've been using `hook_field_widget_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter()` for years.  And, of course, in Drupal 10, it has been deprecated.

I am trying to add a hook to the file attachments widget. I just want to add a text box to each file that is attached. Each time a file is added to the form, a new text box is added for that file. This is the code I am using.

```php
function solrai_field_widget_file_generic_form_alter(&$element, FormStateInterface $form_state, $context) {
  // Do not add the text field if the file has not been uploaded.
  if (empty($element['#default_value']['fids'])) {
    return;
  }

  // Check if the field is either field_public_files or field_private_files.
  if (in_array($element['#field_name'], ['field_public_files', 'field_private_files'])) {
    // Add the source URL text field.
    $element['source_url'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Source URL'),
      '#size' => 90,
      '#weight' => 0.006,
    ];
  }
}
```

How do I duplicate this behavior using `hook_field_widget_complete_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter()`?

I've been trying for hours to get this done with AI, and just can't get there. The closest I get is getting the text box added when the form first comes up, but when I add a file to the form, the box disappears.  The expected behavior is for a new box for the new file to be added to the form.
This  the code I was working with.

```php
function solrai_field_widget_complete_file_generic_form_alter(&$field_widget_complete_form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $context) {
  $logger = \Drupal::service('logger.factory')->get('solrai');
  if (isset($field_widget_complete_form['widget']) && is_array($field_widget_complete_form['widget'])) {
    foreach ($field_widget_complete_form['widget'] as $key => &$file_widget) {
      if (is_array($file_widget) && isset($file_widget['#type']) && $file_widget['#type'] === 'managed_file') {
        if (isset($file_widget['#default_value']['target_id']) && !empty($file_widget['#default_value']['target_id'])) {
          $file_widget['source_url'] = [
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#title' => t('Source URL'),
            '#size' => 90,
          ];
        }
      }
    }
  }
  else {
    $logger->warning("The 'widget' key is not set or not an array.");
  }
}
```

> [image: screenshot]

> [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

`hook_field_widget_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter()` is replaced by `hook_field_widget_single_element_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter()`.

See the change record [Streamline Field Widget Hooks](https://www.drupal.org/node/3180429).

It's not replaced by `hook_field_widget_complete_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter()`. However, it's possible to use it to alter single items but then you need to walk through the form array of the entire widget. It's easier to use the direct replacement.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I read this: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_single_element_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter/9.3.x  which seemed to indicate that I needed the "complete" hook since the widget could contain multiple fields with multiple files each.

Comment: That's a one-to-one replacement, only the name has changed. So whatever worked for the old hook will work for the new one. For a multi-value field the hook will be called multiple times. You find the field delta in $context.

Comment: THANK YOU!  That was exactly the information I needed.  Wish I had known this in the beginning!

Answer (score 0):

It took hours to figure out because the extent to which your code needs to change is not documented anywhere I could find.  I had to painstakingly parse through the data and cobble together the solution through trial and error.  I don't know if this is the best way, but this is the only way I could get it to work.

Here is another, more simple example of the original deprecated hook.

```php
function sbn_field_widget_file_generic_form_alter(&$element, FormStateInterface $form_state, $context) {
  $node = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();

  if (empty($element['#default_value']['fids'])) {
    return;
  }

  if ($element['#field_name'] === 'field_public_files') {
    $element['switch_to_private'] = [
      '#type' => 'checkbox',
      '#title' => t('Switch to private'),
      '#weight' => 0.007,
    ];
  }
  elseif ($element['#field_name'] === 'field_private_files') {
    $element['switch_to_public'] = [
      '#type' => 'checkbox',
      '#title' => t('Switch to public'),
      '#weight' => 0.007,
    ];
  }
}
```

This is what it took to replace the functionality.

```php
function sbn_field_widget_complete_file_generic_form_alter(&$element, FormStateInterface $form_state, $context) {
  $logger = \Drupal::service('logger.factory')->get('sbn');
    
  if (isset($element['widget']) && is_array($element['widget'])) {
    foreach ($element['widget'] as $key => &$file_widget) {
      if (is_array($file_widget) && isset($file_widget['#type']) && $file_widget['#type'] === 'managed_file') {
        if (isset($file_widget['#default_value']['fids']) && !empty($file_widget['#default_value']['fids'])) {
          if ($file_widget['#field_name'] === 'field_public_files') {
            $file_widget['switch_to_private'] = [
              '#type' => 'checkbox',
              '#title' => t('Switch to private'),
              '#weight' => 0.007,
            ];
          }
          elseif ($file_widget['#field_name'] === 'field_private_files') {
            $file_widget['switch_to_public'] = [
              '#type' => 'checkbox',
              '#title' => t('Switch to public'),
              '#weight' => 0.007,
            ];
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  else {
    $logger->warning("The 'widget' key is not set or not an array.");
  }
}
```